# new data in scatter plot not shown in bounds

Tags: ipad, core-plot

i use coreplot library 0.9 in my iPad application.
Here, i use a scatter plot with a fixed y-range (no scrolling in y direction), i.e. plot space range = global range (see source code below).
When new data is available (MOC observation) i add data to plot's data array (scatter plot), determine the new y-range required (min/max value in data array) and reload the whole plot.
If the value of the new data is greater than the other values, the plot displays it out of bounds although the plot space has been adapted to the new range.

But:
If the MOC change is not due to inserting new data (bigger than the old ones) but instead due to deleting data (which had the biggest value in plot data array), the result is perfect: The plot uses the full range  --> range adaption (decreasing plot space range) takes place. Why does this not work in the other direction (increasing plot space range), too?

I am really stuck here and would be glad if someone could help me with that. Thanks.

```
-(void) mocChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    ...
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refresh) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];  
}

- (void) setYAxisValueRange
{
    ...
    myOwnPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(minDisplay)
                                                         length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(maxDisplay)];
    // disable "scrolling" in y-direction
    myOwnPlotSpace.globalYRange = myOwnPlotSpace.yRange;
}

- (void) refresh
{
    [dataForPlot removeAllObjects];
    [self preparePlotData]; // put data into plot's data array
    [self setYAxisValueRange]; // looks for min / max values in data
    [myPlot reloadData];
}
```

These screenshots show the situation (since i am new to Stack Overflow, i am not yet allowed to post pictures): http://gallery.me.com/timoseeberger#100038&view=grid&bgcolor=black&sel=5

1) Initial display of plot (everything is fine):
file: screenshot_graph_initial

2) I add new value (200) to plot --> display out of bounds (upper end)
file: screenshot_graph_adding200

3) I remove values 200 and 150 from plot --> plot display adapts perfectly
file: screenshot_graph_deleting150

4) I add new value (40) to plot --> display out of bounds (lower end)
file: screenshot_graph_adding40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot ranges have a starting location and length. Your location is ok; use `maxDisplay - minDisplay` for the length.

Make sure that your plot uses the plot space that you're updating:

```
[graph addPlot:myPlot toPlotSpace:myOwnPlotSpace];
```

Comment: Thank you, Eric, for pointing this out to me. This is actually a bug in my code (leading to plot area being too big). But even with this fix, the problem remains. I will add links to screenshots that demonstrate the issue.

Comment: As soon as i have the necessary privilege, i will vote your answer up.

Comment: If I've answered your question satisfactorily, you can "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, i found the reason for the behavior and how to fix it:
i removed this line from the method "setYAxisValueRange":

```
myOwnPlotSpace.globalYRange = myOwnPlotSpace.yRange;
```

Setting the globalYRange to the current y-range at startup keeps the graph from updating its display properly when the current range and globalYRange are changed later on. It seems to internally store the initial value of globalYRange until the end of time.
I do not know if this is a bug in CorePlot or i just lack understanding about its usage.
Either way, the fix works fine for me. I do not need to set globalYRange anyway, because i keep the plot from vertical scrolling via the delegate method "plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:"

I hope my answer is helpful for anyone falling in the same pit.
If someone has a more detailed explanation about the issue, i am eager to read it.

Comment: This is by design. Any change to the plot space `yRange` is constrained to the `globalYRange`. To avoid this, set the `globalYRange` to nil before changing the `yRange` and reset it afterwards. The `xRange` and `globalXRange` behave the same way.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I will keep this in mind for future development.